# How can I code this algorithm, called Heap Select, in java?

Tags: java, algorithm, heap

It should work like this:

It should use two min-heap, called H1 and H2. H1 is built based on the input vector and it should not be modified later on. H2 initially has only one node, H1's radix. At the i^th iteration, for i that goes from 1 to k-1, the algorithm should extract H2's radix, which corresponds to a xi node in H1, and it should reinsert in H2 the nodes that follow xi in H1 Heap. After k-1 iterations H2's radix should correspond t the k^th smallest element of the input vector.

This is what I have so far, but it does not work.

```
public class HeapSelect { 

  public static void main(String args[]) { 

    List <Integer> intList=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] strNums = null;
    if (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        strNums = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
    }
    if (strNums != null) {
        for (String strNum: strNums) {
            try {
                intList.add(Integer.parseInt(strNum.trim()));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Invalid input");
                break;
            }
        }
    }


    int[] arr= new int[intList.size()];
    int index = 0;
    for(int i : intList){
        arr[index] = i;
        index++;
    }

    int k = scanner.nextInt();

    int n = arr.length; 

    MinHeap H1 = new MinHeap(n+1); 

    for (int i=0; i < n; i++) {
        H1.insert(arr[i]);
    }

    H1.minHeap();

    MinHeap H2 = new MinHeap(n+1); 
    H2.insert(H1.Heap[1]);

    for (int j=1; j <= k - 1; j++) {
        for (int i=j+1; i <= n; i++) {
            H2.insert(H1.Heap[i]);
        }
        H2.remove();
    }
    System.out.println("result " + H2.remove());
}
```

}

Comment: *"but it does not work."* In what way doesn't it work, and what input are you testing it on? Is there an error (if so, include the full stack trace)? Does it give wrong outputs (if so, include the expected result vs. actual result)? Does it fail in some other way (e.g. infinite loop)? Please see [ask] and write a [mcve].

Comment: Your explanation and your code make no sense. Is the purpose of this just to find the kth smallest element in the input vector?

Comment: the inputs are like this: (the vector on one line) 1 3 7 2 5 (and, on a new line, the kth element) 2. In this exemple the algorithm should output 2 obviously

Comment: yes, the purpose is to find the kth smallest element, but since it is a school project I need to reach the result through the steps that I explained, not in a different way

Comment: as it is right now, it just shows a result that is not the correct one

Comment: You use the word "radix" in your description. Do you perhaps mean "root"?

Comment: You say that you must reach the result using the steps that you explained. But the approach you've posted is completely nonsensical, especially the part about a nested loop that adds a huge number of items to the `H2` heap. Are you sure you interpreted the instructions correctly? Can you post the *actual* assignment?

Comment: Yes I mean root, sorry for that

Comment: unfortunatly the istructions are in italian, I tried to translate them in the description, but if it can be useful here there are:

Comment: Questo algoritmo di selezione utilizza due min-heap, denominate H1 e H2. La prima heap H1 é costruita a partire dal vettore fornito in input in tempo lineare e non viene modificata. La seconda heap H2 contiene inizialmente un solo nodo, corrispondente alla radice di H1. All'i-esima iterazione, per i che va da 1 a k−1, l'algoritmo estrae la radice di H2, che corrisponde a un nodo xi in H1, e reinserisce in H2 i nodi successori di xi nella heap H1. Dopo k−1 iterazioni, la radice di H2 corrisponderà al k-esimo elemento più piccolo del vettore fornito in input.

Answer (score 0):

As your algorithm reads, on fourth last line, you need to **remove from H1, not H2.** Also remove the inner loop, take the insert statement to outer loop. Otherwise you’re just adding and removing top of H1 not going anywhere beyond the smallest element. And in the end, print H1.remove() for kth smallest int.

Maybe you’ve solved it already, but you can do it with just one heap. Insert all the elements into the minheap. To find the k smallest integers, just take out the root integers k times into a integer array/list. After that report whatever you have in list(answers). If you want to restore the heap, just jam the list integers back in. O(n) for heap making, and k.log(n) to  get the results. If you want maximum k elements, start with maxheap.